# How to test default case when using Junit Parameterized.class

Tags: junit4, parameterized

I have an old version API: Foo(). Now I extend the API to Foo(false), Foo(true) and Foo() should still work as before.

Right now I am using Parameterized.class to do Junit, and the parameter list is {null, false, true}. I want to write the testcase as:

```
@Test 
public void fooTest() {
    Foo(parameter);
}
```

But Foo(parameter) cannot test Foo(), so I have to write the test code as:

```
@Test 
public void fooTest() {
   if (parameter == null) 
       Foo();
   else 
       Foo(parameter);
}
```

Is there any simple way to write the test case so that I do not need to check whether parameter is null or not? I ask this because the original test cases before I extend API are already there in many places (see below) and I do not want to change the test code too much. :

```
@Test 
public void fooTest() {
    Foo();
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific. Are you talking about a constructor for a frequently used test object? Or a static method? I think a real-life example might help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to put the Foo-Object (instead of the constructor arguments) into the parameters, i.e. `{Foo(false), Foo(true),Foo()}` instead of `{null, false, true}`

Yet review your example. Probably it is an abstraction of a real problem. If not:

- assertions are missing, these should be contained in the parameters (otherwise you get the if-problem in the assertion phase).
- testing with 3 parameter values is easier done with 3 simple (un-parameterized) unittests

And you could of course put your default constructor into a separate (un-parametereized) test class.

Which alternative is the best depends heavily on the real problem behind your abstraction.